# Ratio of circle's quadrant and circle

Tags: geometry, circles, recreational-mathematics

You are given a circle's quadrant and you are supposed to calculate the ratio of its circumference and the whole circle's circumference.

Which one of these is right:
(A): 1 over 4 (B): 4+Pi over 4*Pi (C): 4+Pi over 2*Pi (D): 4*Pi over 4+Pi (E): 3 over four

I think it's B. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean "a circle's quadrant" and what do you mean "its circumference"?

Comment: Okay, I googled.  What is the formula for the circumference of a quadrant?  And what is the formula for the circumference of a circle?  What is the ratio between them?  Where do you have problems answering those questions?

Comment: I know the formulas, I just need someone to confirm it.

Comment: How in the pluperfect hell are we supposed to confirm your results if you don't tell us what your results were?!!?!!?!!?!!?!!?!!?!!?

Comment: Give your reason and I'll tell you if it is right.

Comment: My reasoning was that it's choice B, because it's clearly not 1 over four, it's also not 3 over 4. It cannot be D, because the whole circle's circumference cannot be 4+Pi. It could be C, but I think that the perimeter of the whole circle is bigger than one quadrants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumference of a circle is $2\pi r$.

A quadrant has $\frac 14$ of that or $1/2\pi r$ as an arc plus two radii as legs.  So the perimeter of a quadrant is \frac 14 \pi 4 + 2r$.

So the ratio is $1/2 \pi r + 2r : 2\pi r$ /~/ $\pi + 4: 4\pi$

which is B).